# Why does calloc always returns NULL when I pass a "big" size?

Tags: c, malloc, calloc

This is my code (it is and **must** be **pure C**):

```
unsigned long buffSize = 65536; /* 64 KB */
char *block;

block = calloc(1, buffSize);
if (block == NULL)
{
    /* This is always triggered */
}
```

I want a 64 KB of zeroed memory that I will use in a loop somewhere else in my application.

Unfortunatly `calloc` always return `NULL`. When I use it with 64 (bytes) it works.

I'm not sure how to allocate "bigger" memory blocks like in my example?

**Edit:** After reading comments, here are some clarifications:

1. `malloc` and `memset` have the same behavior with the same `buffSize`.
2. `sizeof(size_t) == 2` while `sizeof(unsigned long) == 4` so it's 16-bit.
3. The target platform is MS-DOS 6.22.

So under a 16 bits system how can you create a `char *` of 64 KB zero-filled?

Comment: This is most likely an OS/buildtree specific response, so...OS Build Tree?

Comment: does malloc and memset work?

Comment: Crazy idea, `calloc(buffSize,1)`. Also try `unsigned long buffSize = 65536L;'. I have no idea what the limits are on your platform.

Comment: 64KB does not strike me as all that large. I'll ask the obvious question, how much memory does your system have available? May I suggest that you try defining buffSize as hving type `size_t` or even plain old `int`. If that doesn't work it might be interesting to repeatedly reduce the buff size by half and see if there is a size that does work.

Comment: Is this on a 16bit OS? Eg. MS/DOS?

Comment: `unsigned long` must be at least 32 bits, but `size_t` could conceivably be 16 bits. What is `sizeof (size_t)` on your system? Does `malloc(buffSize)` return a null pointer? Try a range of values between `64` and `65536`; is that a particular size where it starts failing?

Comment: If you are on a 16 bit system with a non compliant compiler, then 65536 may overflow to 0.

Comment: Edited the question to clarify some points.

Comment: Look for `farmalloc` or similar function. (OMG farmalloc, how many moons have passed, didn't expect to meet you again...)

Comment: MS-DOS... Isn't the memory model `tiny` by chance?

Comment: You can try to do something like `calloc(256, 256)`.

Comment: Excuse me for a c++ quote of a much newer standard, but "[std::size_t](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t) can store the maximum size of a theoretically possible object..."; your `size_t` cannot hold 65536, so it will definitely not work.

Comment: Must be a Windows thing. I can `calloc(1000, 1000000);` (a gigabyte), no problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've said that `sizeof (size_t) == 2` (this is for MS-DOS 6.22).

That means that the maximum value of `size_t` is `65535`.

```
unsigned long buffSize = 65536; /* 64 KB */
```

No problem so far. `unsigned long` must be at least 32 bits (and is 32 bits on your system), so it can easily hold the value `65536`.

```
char *block;

block = calloc(1, buffSize);
```

Both arguments to `calloc` are of type `size_t`. Any argument that's not of type `size_t` is implicitly converted. Converting `65536` to `size_t` yields `0`. So you're requesting an allocation of 0 bytes. The behavior of such an allocation is implementation-defined; it can return a null pointer, or it can return a unique non-null pointer, similar to `malloc(1)` except that you can't necessarily dereference it. Your implementation apparently does the former.

`calloc` takes two arguments, both of type `size_t`. Their values are not simply multiplied to yield a result of type `size_t`. Instead, `calloc` must either successfully allocate the number of bytes specified *or* fail to do so and return a null pointer.

In principle, you can write:

```
block = calloc(64, 1024);
```

or something similar. If it succeeds, it will allocate a 65536-byte object.

But since `size_t` is only 16 bits, that almost certainly means that the implementation cannot create objects bigger than at most 65535 bytes. There's no actual prohibition against creating objects bigger than `SIZE_MAX` bytes, but any implementation that's able to do so would almost certainly make its `size_t` bigger, so that it can represent the size of any object.

(`SIZE_MAX` is the maximum value of the type `size_t`. It's a macro defined in `<stdint.h>`, which was introduced by the C99 standard. Your implementation probably doesn't support `<stdint.h>`. The expression `((size_t)-1)` is equivalent.)

You're probably out of luck, unless you use a different implementation (which might mean using the same compiler with different options).

Perhaps you can redesign your program so it can use, for example, two 32768-byte objects rather than a single 65536-byte object (though that might not be supported either).

MS-DOS systems support (supported?) multiple memory models, some of which might permit you to do what you want. I don't know the details. Consult your compiler's documentation for more information.

Comment: I tried `block = calloc(64, 1024);` but it seems the maximum I can do is `60, 1024`... Maybe it's the compiler or the system, I don't know.

Comment: @AlexV: As I said, if `size_t` is 16 bits, then it's very unlikely that your implementation can support an object bigger than 65535 bytes (and the limit could be smaller than that). I'm afraid that's probably the best answer you're going to get -- unless you're able to invoke your compiler in a mode that permits larger objects (look for "memory models").

Answer (score 1):

For 16 bit real mode, you may need to specify "huge" model, which uses far pointers to support arrays > 65536 in size. It's possible that compact or large model might work, using a single fixed segment value and variable offset to handle a buffer size of 65536. I don't know what tool set you are using, but there should be a command line parameter to specify the memory model the program will be using. For Microsoft 16 bit real mode compilers the parameter is /AH for huge, /AC for compact, and /AL for large.

Wiki link: [Intel Memory Models](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Memory_Model#Memory_models)